# Retrieving token and secret from gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken python object

Tags: python, oauth, gdata, access-token

I'm following Google's great [sample code](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html#Examples) for three-legged OAuth.

Specifically, I'm looking at the python version of the code. I'm stuck between 'Upgrading to an access token' and 'Using an access token'.

In 'Upgrading to an access token', there is a line of code as follows:

```
access_token = client.GetAccessToken(request_token)
```

In 'Using an access token', there is a line of code as follows:

```
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken(CONSUMER_KEY,
                                               CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                               TOKEN,
                                               TOKEN_SECRET, 
                                               gdata.gauth.ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

I assume `TOKEN` and `TOKEN_SECRET` are packed into the `access_token` object (`gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken`), but how do I retrieve them?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question, since I need to persist the token and secret to a database.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.

`access_token` is of type `gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken`. So instead of trying to pass in the individual arguments, I could just do this:

```
client.auth_token = access_token
```